# Any chance to simplify these nested loops?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm creating a shoppingcart manager for my school project and there is a method to remove an item from the cart.

```
        public String removeItem(String itemName) {
            String removeOutput = "Something is wrong";
            int CAPACITY = 10;
            ShoppingCartManager SCM = new ShoppingCartManager();
            System.out.println("Enter name of the item:");
            itemName = SCM.input.nextLine();
            for(int i=0; i < CAPACITY; i++) {
                if(itemNames[i] != null) {
                    if(itemNames[i].equals(itemName)) {
                        itemNames[i] = null;
                        costs[i] = 0;
                        for(int j=0; j < CAPACITY; j++) {
                            if(cartItems[j].toString().contains(itemName)) {
                                for(int k = 0; k < quantities[i]; k++) {
                                    cartItems[j + k] = null;
                                }
                                break;
                            } 
                        }
                        quantities[i] = 0;
                        removeOutput = ("["+itemName+"] is removed from your shopping cart. ");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        removeOutput = ("["+itemName+"] not found in cart. ");
                    }
                }
                
            }
            return removeOutput;
        }
```

This is the best I can do and the outcome is as expected, I'm just curious if it is possible to simplify that super long nested loop in the method.

Comment: You can extract methods to make the code easier to understand. Paradoxically, this will increase the total number of lines.

Comment: `if(itemNames[i] != null) { if(itemNames[i].equals(itemName)) {` can be reduced to `if(itemName.equals(itemNames[i])) {`

Comment: {actually it is wrong IMHO to (try to) simplify some code without knowing the data structure and specification details. The posted code is using at least 3 arrays, it uses `equals` mixed with `contains`, strings and (apparently) objects, ... hard to understand, also "simplify" can have different meanings: less lines, simpler to understand, no data duplication/triplication, ...}

Comment: Is there an absolute requirement to use an array for the items? Using a List (typically an ArrayList) instead would remove at least half of your code, and most of the boring parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use guard clauses to "un-nest" nested if-statements. This is where you specify conditions to skip the data instead of what conditions you want in order to continue to process the data

```
if(itemNames[i] != null) {
    if(itemNames[i].equals(itemName)) {
        //... more nested loops etc.
    }
}
```

can be extracted for:

```
if(itemNames[i] == null) {
    return;  //or break/continue depending if its inside a loop or a function
}
//other guard clause if statements
if(itemNames[i].equals(itemName)) {
    //... processing
}
```

of course, if you have more if conditions nested you can then extract them all out to make it more readable.

As for nested for loops, that depends on how well you recognize the process of working with your data structure. Can you do it in one for loop? Can you extract one of the loops into a method and call it so that the code looks more readable even if it is still a nested for loop?